# How to join on JDV and not to push down join to data source

Tags: redhat-datavirt

Problem: I am trying to create a wide view (~5000 columns), which works across data sources fine JDV. However, when I try to create the view with a join on 2+ table from data source, the optimizer pushes down the join to the source. The current source cannot handle more then 1600 columns.

Example: When trying to join Member_DX1 and Member_DX2 at client, JDV pushes the `enter code here`combined join to postgres as one getting the too max column error.

```
/* TABLE 1 */

CREATE VIEW Member_DX1 (
    MEMB_BID Integer
     , DX130402000000 Integer
     , DX180608000000 Integer
     , DX20401070000 Integer
.... /* 1000 more */
as
SELECT dx.memb_bid
, case dx.EPI_1_DX4 when 130402000000 then 1 else 0 END as  DX130402000000                                              
, case dx.EPI_1_DX4 when 180608000000 then 1 else 0 END as  DX180608000000                                              
, case dx.EPI_1_DX4 when 20401070000 then 1 else 0 END as  DX20401070000
...
FROM BDR.ENH_EPI_DETAIL dx 

/* TABLE 2 */

CREATE VIEW Member_DX2 (
    MEMB_BID Integer
     , DX200102010000 Integer
     , DX90125000000 Integer
     , DX160603070000 Integer
... /* 1000 more ...
SELECT dx.memb_bid  /* FOREIGN TABLE */
, case dx.EPI_1_DX4 when 200102010000 then 1 else 0 END as  DX200102010000                                              
, case dx.EPI_1_DX4 when 90125000000 then 1 else 0 END as  DX90125000000                                                
, case dx.EPI_1_DX4 when 160603070000 then 1 else 0 END as  DX160603070000      
...`enter code here`
FROM BDR.ENH_EPI_DETAIL dx
```

then my query in (e.g. dBeaver) looks like this:

```
SELECT * from Member_DX1 dx1
join Member_DX2 dx2 
on dx1.MEMB_BID = dx2.MEMB_BID
```

Answer (score 1):

> The current source cannot handle more then 1600 columns.

Can you capture that as an issue for Teiid?  Then we can take appropriate compensating action automatically.

> then my query in (e.g. dBeaver) looks like this:

If you see this issue affecting all of your user queries, then you can turn join support off at the translator level via translator overrides - SupportsInnerJoin, SupportsOuterJoins, etc..  If there is a pk/fk relationship and you can modify the metadata, you can add an extension property allow-join as false to prevent the pushdown - see Join Compensation http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/Federated_Optimizations.html